# Wireshark how do I see data from a phone on the same network

Tags: windows, kali-linux, wireshark, sniffing

So I am wondering how can I see the data on wireshark?
I have my router setup to where there is no password so I can automatically connect whatever devices on to my network.
First I connect my phone and next I run wireshark and I have a usb wifi adapter to capture/inject packets.
I also have wireshark in monitor mode and promiscuous mode as well.
I feel like I should be able to see all traffic from my phone right, and not have to decrypt the 802.11 traffic since there is no password? but i only see my phone going to the destination of broadcast only. I want to be able to see all the traffic.

What am I missing because I feel like I should be able to see all kinds of traffic from my phone, but I only see broadcast only.
I want to be able to get whatever traffic that is going on between my phone and the internet such as using apps or browsing.
Also I have an AirPcap usb adapter. And this is all for testing and learning purposes, thanks.

Comment: you need to sniff the wireless packets in monitor mode, and be able to decrypt them with the password if the network has one. You're only seeing broadcast because currently you're listening to your own connection with the router, and broadcast are the only packets from the phone that are destined to your device. In monitor mode it will gather packets from all wireless clients.

Comment: Is the interface on the same band and channel as the network?